# Group by and count values of the last 24 hrs

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have ad df which looks like this :

```
user_id   session_id     timestamp          
141.0      1.0   20190418 02:23:56.000 
141.0      2.0   20190416 19:51:57.000 
141.0      3.0   20190415 14:47:53.000   
121.0      4.0   20190414 13:57:55.000    
121.0      5.0   20190414 06:23:01.000  
121.0      6.0   20190412 15:32:57.000
```

I'm trying to apply a lambda function with a group by which counts for every user_id the number of sessions in the last 24 hours from the session's timestamp:

The result should be :

```
user_id   session_id     timestamp            24-HourCount  
141.0      1.0   20190418 02:23:56.000             0
141.0      2.0   20190416 19:51:57.000             0
141.0      3.0   20190415 14:47:53.000             na  
121.0      4.0   20190414 13:57:55.000             3
121.0      5.0   20190414 06:23:01.000             1
121.0      6.0   20190413 15:32:57.000             na
```

I tried to group by and count the number of rows (all sessions are distinct values) but I'm getting an error.

```py
df['24-HourCount'] = df.groupby('user_id')['timestamp'].transform(lambda x:\
          x.between(x.max()- dt.timedelta(days=1),x.max())).count()))

tried also applying the function:
def func(dfx):
    k=dfx[dfx.between(dfx[0]-dt.timedelta(days=1),dfx[0])].count()
    return(k)

df['24-HourCount']=df.groupby('user_id').apply(func)
```

Thanks!!

Comment: Where do you define your `between` function?

Comment: It should be the pandas series between function